# Best Practices for Managing Org Profiles & Permissions

Tags: profile, permissions, bestpractice

Are there any books, tutorials or whitepapers out there that recommend a strategy how to cope with the complexity of profiles and permissions in big Salesforce orgs?

You find fragments of that in blogs and help articles but I am looking for a complete view of this topic including:

- How to migrate from profiles to permission (sets)
- How to govern the quality of single perm sets, so they don't overlap too much.
- Which tools support managing permissions

Comment: Robert, wouldn't this have been easier to answer in separate questions which are more specific ?

Comment: @SamuelDeRycke No because my question was not about specific tool or practices. It was about whether there exist a somewhat authorative guide to this topic. I know the fragments out there but they don't form a consistent view on that important topic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question. Keep in mind that sharing and visibility now has an architect level certification all to itself. I don't think any single post here can encapsulate all that you need to know to manage it effectively. But to start off with what salesforce recommends, [check out Trailhead's official "Architect Journey: Sharing and Visibility" cert guides here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/credentials/sharingandvisibilitydesigner). You can check out the "Sharing and Visibility" section."  These were resources hand picked by current Technical Architects.

I'd also check out [Dreamforce Video - so many profiles so little time](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LcqS1KvMvK8)

Some other discussions on Best Practices

- [Configuring Salesforce Profiles: Tips I Wish Someone Told Me from the Start](http://opfocus.com/configuring-salesforce-profiles-tips-i-wish-someone-told-me-from-the-start/)
- Salesforce Blog [Where Permission Sets shine](http://blogs.perficient.com/salesforce/2012/05/17/where-permission-sets-shine/)
- [Permission Set Best Practice: Reuse, Reduce, Recycle](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2011/12/permission-set-best-practice-reuse-reduce-recycle.html)
- [Permission Sets: The Elegant Solution to Preventing Permissions
  Chaos](https://admin.salesforce.com/permission-sets-elegant-solution-preventing-permissions-chaos)
- [How to build a rocks solid role heirarchy](https://www.adminhero.com/how-to-build-a-rock-solid-role-hierarchy/)

Getting into actual tools to help you out, for comparing you have several good options, including:

- [SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html)
- Force.com Migration Tool
- Eclipse IDE (or some other Salesforce IDE) and any diff tool
- [This Heroku app](https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/)
- [This Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/profile-comparator-for-sa/ijbipklcimjilmnaffocmjkfddhpaadg)

For managing permissions, the main tool I know of is
[The Permissioner](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008XYMlEAO), or list views of profiles.

Comment: My question was not about specific tools or practices but about whether there exist an authoritative and broad guide to this topic. I know the fragments out there but they don't form a consistent view on that important topic. But there are some nuggets of wisdom in you answer and it's the only one...so you will get the bounty. ;-)

Comment: Also check out this Salesforce Trailhead like for all the needed information on the Cert exam: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Salesforce-Certified-Sharing-and-Visibility-Designer-Exam-Guide